# Calling JS function onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call this Javascript function. When I hit my button, there is nothing loading. I set an id for my button. With the onclick I load the function onLinkedInLoad. But is it not that function I should call to activate the script? Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Try Me</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("btn").onclick = onLinkedInLoad;
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
      api_key: myKey
      authorize: true
      onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

      // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
        function onLinkedInLoad() {
          IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
        }

      // Handle the successful return from the API call
      function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }

      // Handle an error response from the API call
      function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      // Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn
      function shareContent() {

        // Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared
        var payload = {
          "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG",
          "visibility": {
            "code": "anyone"
          }
        };

        IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
          .method("POST")
          .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
          .result(onSuccess)
          .error(onError);
      }

        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Update:
I get this in my console:

```
18 Uncaught ReferenceError: onLinkedInLoad is not defined
www.linkedin.com/uas/js/userspace?v=0.0.1191-RC8.56309-1429&apiKey=myKey&authorize=true&onLoad=onLinkedInLoad&secure=1&:
22 Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.
```

I putted my APIkey in also. I just replaced in the code here with "myKey". I also tried with `.addEventListener('click', onLinkedInLoad)`, but still nothing happens

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Instead of `.onclick = onLinkedInLoad` try `.addEventListener('click', onLinkedInLoad)`

Comment: have you tried <button id="btn" onclick="onLinkedInLoad()">Try Me</button>

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answers. I just made an update on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load the function definition script before the call script. Or better, take all the scripts in another file and just load that on your HTML.

I've tried your code on js fiddle and it works by doing that.

Comment: Do you maybe have time to give me a link to the fiddle? I would be really happy about that. Best regards

Comment: Here is the link. jsfiddle.net/w3pjuxd6/

Comment: Thank you a lot. What I am really in doubt is. As it is now I call an alert. But I have to call the LinkedIn API, so I get the share function. Am I on the wrong path here?

Comment: For the first error, try to extract all your Javascript code to an external file, and load it after document ready. 

For the second error, is the path (/people/~/shares?format=json) you are using correct? Maybe using the full path may work, but I'm not sure.